# Can the actionPerformed method be split into two method, and, if yes, how?

Tags: java

So basically what the question says. My actionPerformed method exceeds the 65535 byte limit and I'm trying to get it to work. I've tried actually splitting it into two methods in one class, but that doesn't work; I've tried putting a chunk of it into a second class and calling it (though I'm not sure where in the code to call it, I've tried to do it in the main actionPerformed method, and that obviously didn't work). the chunk that's breaking it:

```
              if(source.equals(i1))
              {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i1.setText("x");
                       i1.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       i1.setText("o"); 
                       i1.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
               if(source.equals(i2))
               {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i2.setText("x");
                       i2.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       i2.setText("o"); 
                       i2.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
               if(source.equals(i3))
               {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i3.setText("x");
                       i3.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {   
                       i3.setText("o"); 
                       i3.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
               if((i1.getText().equals("x") && i2.getText().equals("x") && i3.getText().equals("x")) 
                       || (i1.getText().equals("o") && i2.getText().equals("o") && i3.getText().equals("o")))
               {
                  if(i1.getText().equals("x") || i2.getText().equals("x") || i3.getText().equals("x"))
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }
               if(source.equals(i4))
               {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i4.setText("x");
                       i4.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       i4.setText("o"); 
                       i4.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
               if(source.equals(i5))
               {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i5.setText("x");
                       i5.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       i5.setText("o"); 
                       i5.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
               if(source.equals(i6))
               {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i6.setText("x");
                       i6.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       i6.setText("o"); 
                       i6.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
               if((i4.getText().equals("x") && i5.getText().equals("x") && i6.getText().equals("x")) 
                       || (i4.getText().equals("o") && i5.getText().equals("o") && i6.getText().equals("o")))
               {
                  if(i4.getText().equals("x") || i5.getText().equals("x") || i6.getText().equals("x"))
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }
               if(source.equals(i7))
               {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i7.setText("x");
                       i7.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       i7.setText("o"); 
                       i7.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
               if(source.equals(i8))
               {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i8.setText("x");
                       i8.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       i8.setText("o"); 
                       i8.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
               if(source.equals(i9))
               {
                   if(input2.equals("x"))
                   {
                       i9.setText("x");
                       i9.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       i9.setText("o");
                       i9.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               } 
               if((i7.getText().equals("x") && i8.getText().equals("x") && i9.getText().equals("x")) 
                       || (i7.getText().equals("o") && i8.getText().equals("o") && i9.getText().equals("o")))
               {
                  if(i7.getText().equals("x") || i8.getText().equals("x") || i9.getText().equals("x"))
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }    
               if((i1.getText().equals("x") && i5.getText().equals("x") && i9.getText().equals("x")) 
                       || (i1.getText().equals("o") && i5.getText().equals("o") && i9.getText().equals("o")))
               {
                  if(i1.getText().equals("x") || i5.getText().equals("x") || i9.getText().equals("x"))
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }
               if((i3.getText().equals("x") && i5.getText().equals("x") && i7.getText().equals("x")) 
                       || (i3.getText().equals("o") && i5.getText().equals("o") && i7.getText().equals("o")))
               {
                  if(i3.getText().equals("x") || i5.getText().equals("x") || i7.getText().equals("x"))
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }
               if((i1.getText().equals("x") && i4.getText().equals("x") && i7.getText().equals("x")) 
                       || (i1.getText().equals("o") && i4.getText().equals("o") && i7.getText().equals("o")))
               {
                  if(i1.getText().equals("x") || i4.getText().equals("x") || i7.getText().equals("x"))
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }
               if((i2.getText().equals("x") && i5.getText().equals("x") && i8.getText().equals("x")) 
                       || (i2.getText().equals("o") && i5.getText().equals("o") && i8.getText().equals("o")))
               {
                  if(i2.getText().equals("x") || i5.getText().equals("x") || i8.getText().equals("x"))
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }
               if((i3.getText().equals("x") && i6.getText().equals("x") && i9.getText().equals("x")) 
                       || (i3.getText().equals("o") && i6.getText().equals("o") && i9.getText().equals("o")))
               {
                  if(i3.getText().equals("x") || i6.getText().equals("x") || i9.getText().equals("x"))
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      i1.setEnabled(false);
                      i2.setEnabled(false);
                      i3.setEnabled(false);
                      i4.setEnabled(false);
                      i5.setEnabled(false);
                      i6.setEnabled(false);
                      i7.setEnabled(false);
                      i8.setEnabled(false);
                      i9.setEnabled(false);
                  }
              }
```

Comment: I'm quite concerned with the structure of that code. its not very verbose in what it's doing thus making it harder to read and understand; its also riddled with nested ifs which only adds to the readability and maintainability issues. Your best bet is to find repeated code and get it into their own methods that you then call them from your action performed event.

Comment: Is this a tic tac toe game?

Comment: yes, well super tic tac toe. 'i' is the "quadrant", the numbers are the actually button numbers.

Comment: I suggest that you get as much of the repeated code into methods that are called. that should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
              i1.setEnabled(false);
              i2.setEnabled(false);
              i3.setEnabled(false);
              i4.setEnabled(false);
              i5.setEnabled(false);
              i6.setEnabled(false);
              i7.setEnabled(false);
              i8.setEnabled(false);
              i9.setEnabled(false);
```

i dont know how to shorten the `conditions` in your method but i found these set of lines in the entire code.you can move them to a method that will help you to shorten the code in your program.

```
         public void foo(){
                  i1.setEnabled(false);
                  i2.setEnabled(false);
                  i3.setEnabled(false);
                  i4.setEnabled(false);
                  i5.setEnabled(false);
                  i6.setEnabled(false);
                  i7.setEnabled(false);
                  i8.setEnabled(false);
                  i9.setEnabled(false);
         }
```

and you can use a method for this action too . i assume that `input` is a `jtextField`.

```
               if(input2.equals("x"))
               {
                   i1.setText("x");
                   i1.setEnabled(false);
               }
               else
               {
                   i1.setText("o"); 
                   i1.setEnabled(false);
               }
```

use a method to perform this action. ex:-

```
 public void lessCode(JtextField text){
               if(text.equals("x"))
           {
               text.setText("x");
               text.setEnabled(false);
           }
           else
           {
               text.setText("o"); 
               text.setEnabled(false);
           }
               }
```

Comment: thanks. this is really helping. one setEnabled(false) chunk out resolved the error, but for consistency's sake, I'll do the rest of them.

Comment: @ark don't forget to comeback and accept the answer if you find it helpful.